# Python:error inserting json documents in mongodb collection

Tags: python, json, mongodb, file, collections

I'm new to pymongo and mongodb and I have a json file with 157 documents that I want to insert in a collection called Students . I load the json file line by line and import each document inside a list called data . Then I try using the insert_one() method in a loop to insert each document inside the Students collection and I get many errors bellow 
The format of the json file is :

```
 //example of an entry 
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e99cb577a781a4aac69da3c"},"name":"Tanner Wilson","email":"tannerwilson@ontagene.com","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1962"},"address":[{"street":"Halsey Street","city":"Greenwich","postcode":{"$numberInt":"13832"}}]}
```

My code :

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json 

client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')

db  = client['InfoSys']
collection=db['Students']
data=[]

with open('students.json') as f:
   for json_data in f:
       element =json.loads(json_data)
       data.append(element)

'''print(data)''' // the json data can be printed perfectly 

for k in data :
   collection.insert_one(k) //this is where the error happens
```

And I get the errors bellow : 
  
  `File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 698, in insert_one
    session=session),
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 612, in _insert
    bypass_doc_val, session)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 600, in _insert_one
    acknowledged, _insert_command, session)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1491, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1384, in _retry_with_session
    return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 595, in _insert_command
    retryable_write=retryable_write)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 618, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 613, in command
    user_fields=user_fields)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 129, in command
    codec_options, ctx=compression_ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 707, in _op_msg
    flags, command, identifier, docs, check_keys, opts)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$oid' must not start with '$'`

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this issue .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have data in a string format, you need to use `loads()` from the `bson.json_util` library; e.g.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import bson.json_util

client = MongoClient()

db  = client['InfoSys']
collection=db['Students']
data='{"_id":{"$oid":"5e99cb577a781a4aac69da3c"},"name":"Tanner Wilson","email":"tannerwilson@ontagene.com","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1962"},"address":[{"street":"Halsey Street","city":"Greenwich","postcode":{"$numberInt":"13832"}}]}'
collection.insert_one(bson.json_util.loads(data))
print(collection.find_one())
```

result:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e99cb577a781a4aac69da3c'), 'name': 'Tanner Wilson', 'email': 'tannerwilson@ontagene.com', 'yearOfBirth': 1962, 'address': [{'street': 'Halsey Street', 'city': 'Greenwich', 'postcode': 13832}]}
```

Comment: I now receive  errors in 2 lines . I get : `
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bson\json_util.py", line 410, in loads
    return json.loads(s, *args, **kwargs)` and 
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Comment: My example was for a single record. Did you get that working? Once you have that working you need to iterate your list to load each record.

Comment: Yes i iterated through the list using a for loop . Specifically i wrote for k in data:
    collection.insert_one(bson.json_util.loads(k)) . The new errors are: in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict and the second error in loads
    return json.loads(s, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: I spend hours on this problem. Fixed it by changing json.loads() into bson.json_util.loads()